# enable a drupal theme manually (which file to modify)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Ok, let's say i'm a big newby on drupal, and that i want to load a theme (which actually should be enabled, and displaying - currently not). And that i don't have access to the admin part of the install (old site, etc… don't ask why).

Looking for someone to specify me the files to change in order to make this theme work.
Thanks

(We could talk about clearing the cache "manually" too… hate sometimes those all-in-the-admin stuffs, but well…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable a theme 'manually' you'll need to visit the `system` table in your database and set the `status` column to 1 for the record with a `type` of 'theme' and a `name` matching the theme you want to enable.

Manually flushing caches is as simple as running a `DELETE FROM table` for all tables whose name begins with `cache` (e.g. cache, cache_block, cache_content, etc.).

None of what you're trying to find is located in files, almost all of Drupal's config is held in the database (those in settings.php excluded).